# How to synchronize closing socket by two threads?

Tags: java, android, synchronized

I have two threads, one for reading, one for writing data through the same socket. When is problem with connection two threads catch exceptions and try reconnect.To do this they call the same methods

```
   public synchronized void close_connection() {
        try {
            socket.shutdownInput();
            socket.shutdownOutput();
            socket.close();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and after it second one to try establish connection:

```
public synchronized boolean connect() {
            boolean result=true;
            socket = new Socket();
            try {
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(address, port), 500);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        socket.getInputStream()));
                out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                        socket.getOutputStream()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                result=false;

            }
            return result;
        }
```

The problem is how to avoid trying connect with server from two threads one by one immediatly (after connection error - for example afrter closing connection by server). I mean: if one thread tries do connection the second thread should know this and dosen't try do the same but wait for establish connection by first one (to avoid permanent fight threads problem disconnect,connect, disconnect, connect....). I've tried with synchronization but my experience is too small.
Regards,
Artik

Comment: try to google "producer consumer"

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
while(not connected){
   try reconnecting
   if(success){
      //Everything is ok, go on
   } else {
      //sleep for random period of time and retry
   }
}
```

or you can implement the socket operations in an object and share that object between your threads using locks.

Answer (score 0):

Use appropriate mutex locking. This will make sure only one thread will access the connect() portion of your code.